# Webform email twig template questions

Tags: 8, webforms

What is the correct syntax to test if a file has been uploaded in a webform in a twig email template?

For a text area, `{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:question_text_area:value]', webform_submission) %}` works fine but to test if a file has been uploaded, `{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:value]', webform_submission) %}` does not work.

Also, when there's a file uploaded, I want to display in the email only the title of the file ... `{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:delta:format:value]', webform_submission) }}` works but it outputs a link to that file. Is it possible to just have the text of the file name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a great question.

Getting just the filename is not currently supported but you can pull the file's URL using `[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:delta:format:url]`

The current list of supported formats for uploaded files is [here](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformManagedFileBase.php#n352). I created a ticket to 
[add machine name to element submission display formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2959005) so that this information is exposed to site builder.

If you need just the file name, please create a new ticket in the [Webform module's issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform).

Comment: I created a ticket to add a filename format to managed file elements https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2959088#comment-12560276

Comment: Thank you for creating the ticket ... I was going to wait to see if I could extract the filename from the url but even when I put `[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:delta:format:url]` in my email twig template, the output is always a link with the filename. I should have specified my field is a Document File ... maybe it doesn't work with this filetype?

Comment: Also, I tried creating a conditionnal email that would be enabled only if my file field was empty to solve my problem of testing if a file has been uploaded in a twig email template ... is "Empty" the correct Trigger/Value for that use case? I tried it but the email is not sent when the condition is met.

Comment: The `[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:delta:forma:name]` token is now supported in the latest dev release.

If you are finding other bugs please create a ticket in the Webform module's issue queue.
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x

Comment: Sorry about the extra questions, I'll check the issue queue to see if that's been reported. If not, I'll create a ticket.

Comment: I downloaded the latest release. `[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:delta:forma:name]` does not work for me but `[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:name]` does. The submission display option "File name (name)" works. Thank you!